# How can i change items place inside List<string>?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
var test = ExtractImages.imagesUrls.Where(c => c == "is").Concat(q.Where(c => c != "is"));

            downloadFile(ExtractImages.imagesUrls);
```

I tried with the var test. But it's wrong. There are 10 items in the List imagesUrls i need to move them to the first 10 places from index 0 to index 9.

The items are links for example item format in the List:

"http://www.sat24.com/image2.ashx?region=is&time=201701102330&ir=true"

So i need to move all the links with 'is' to be in first places.
'is' i mean that the region is 'is' ( region=is )

Comment: You can [Sort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/234b841s(v=vs.110).aspx) your list using whatever rules you want...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build a new List

```
var newList = new List<string>();
newList.AddRange(oldList.OrderBy(s=>!s.Contains("region=is")));
oldList = newList;
```

or, as suggested by BradleyDotNet, put them together in one statement...

```
var newList = new List<string>();
oldList = newList.AddRange(oldList.OrderBy(s=>!s.Contains("region=is"))).ToList();
```

Comment: Yes, that will work too.  I sense this op is relatively new, so I was showing the logic step by step...  But I modified to show your suggestion

Comment: I'm getting error. My Lists are <string> so i did: List<string> newImagesUrlsList = new List<string>();
            ExtractImages.imagesUrls = newImagesUrlsList.AddRange(ExtractImages.imagesUrls.OrderBy(s => s.Contains("region=is"))); but i'm getting error: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'

Comment: you are missing the `ToList()` at the end

Comment: Ok this is working without errors but it's moving the items to the end of the List in the newList the items are now in the last 10 indexs. But i want to move them to the first 0-9 indexs. var newList = new List<string>();
            newList.AddRange(ExtractImages.imagesUrls.OrderBy(s =>  s.Contains("region=is"))); What should i change ?

Comment: This is working: newList.AddRange(ExtractImages.imagesUrls.OrderByDescending(s => s.Contains("region=is"))); i had to change the OrderBy with OrderByDescending

Comment: Yes, `bool` false sorts before true.  OrderByDescending, or you could have ordered by not contains... `orderBy(‌​s => !s.Contains("region=is")));`